# NSString drawinrect not fills whole rect

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, text, nsstring

I'm having a problem with NSString drawInRect method.
I have a very large text to be painted over a 768x1024 size Rect and I obtain this:

[image: Image text on screen]

As you can see the only text line that reaches the whole screen is the last one, I don't know why other lines don't.
This is my code:

```
//The drawing rectangle
CGRect textRect = CGRectMake(1, 4, 768, 1024);
[[UIColor blackColor] set];
CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(context, kCGTextFillStroke);
//texto_completo is a very large text String
[texto_completo drawInRect:textRect withFont:font lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeCharacterWrap     alignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
CGImageRef cgImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context); 
UIImage *img_con_texto = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:cgImage];
UIGraphicsPopContext();
CGContextRelease(context);
CGImageRelease(cgImage);
```

Could you help me understand this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the APple algorithm is over aggressive.

The best solution is to set the alignment to UITextAlignmentCenter, that is the only way top get the characters flush right. In my test the lime breaks were the same as with alignment UITextAlignmentLeft.

Comment: I tried to set UITextAlignmentCenter even UITextAlignmentRight but I get the same error. Tried to set a smaller rectangle too but the same happens. 
The only way to fix it was to set a bigger font, size but I need small fonts.
Any help please?